# Probability question involving chess

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

John agrees to play chess until he wins one game or loses 3 games. If his probability of winning is 0.6 calculate the expected number of games that will be played.

My Answer
P(win first game)= 0.6
P(lose 3 games)= 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 = 0.064

However, the correct answer is

P(win first game)= 0.6

**P(win 2nd game)= 0.4 x 0.6= 0.24

P(win 3rd game)= 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.6= 0.096**

P(lose 3 games)= 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 = 0.064

My question is, why was the probability of winning the 2nd and 3rd game included? Also, why was winning even included? John won only one game and lost 3 games. If anything shouldn't it have been P(losing 2nd game) and P(losing 3rd game)? I'm extremely lost with this question and I have no idea how they got the bolded answers. Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

As for calculating the expected number of games played, thankfully I know how to solve for it.

Comment: We have not sufficient information. What is the probability that he loses the game (consider that chess also allows a draw) ?

Comment: If John loses the first two games then the third game will decide whether he has won one game (the 3rd) or lost three games

Comment: This is just a matter of understanding the language used.  Rephrased, "*he plays until he wins one game or loses 3 games*" can be rephrased as "*he plays until among the possibly many games that he has played there is at least one time in which he won, or at least three times in which he lost.*"  That is to say, the possible total outcomes that could have happened is that he won the first game (*in which case he has won at least one and ended*), or he lost the first and won the second (*in which case he won at least one and ended*), or lost first two and won third, or lost first three...

Comment: @Peter I think for the sake of this question we can ignore the possibility of a draw. But more interesting might be to let $p$ be the probability of winning and $q$ the probability of drawing...

Comment: As for calculating... recall that for independent events, $Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.  Assuming the results of the games are independent, and assuming that there are no ties, the probability of losing the first game and winning the second game is simply the probability of losing the first game times the probability of winning the second game, which is $0.4\times 0.6$...  Similarly for the next calculation, you just multiply the probabilities of having arrived in that particular case.

Comment: @Peter The question we were given didn't state a draw. And the lose would be 0.4. It wasn't stated either, but I'm assuming that's where the 0.4 in the answer key came from.

Comment: In any case, the question is "calculate the expected number of games that will be played" where the correct answer is presumably $1\times 0.6+2 \times 0.24+3\times 0.096+3\times 0.064=1.56$.  If you just calculated $1\times 0.6+3\times 0.064=0.792$ the answer would be obviously wrong as not even one game would be expected to be played

Comment: @ JMoravitz Ok, so I have a question. When it says P(win 2nd game)= 0.4 x 0.6= 0.24. Does this mean that John may have lost the first game and may have won the second game? Or does it mean that John has lost the first game but won the second game?

Comment: @Henry but why did they use P(win 2nd game) and P(win 3rd game)? We are looking for loses not winnings. I'm still confused about that.

Comment: For P(win 2nd game) they mean that very explicitly John lost the first game and won the second game.  Reworded "win 2nd game" in this context means that the sequence of games ended as a direct result of having won the second game.  Had he won the first game there wouldn't have even *been* a second game for him to play.

Comment: Again, John plays until he either wins a game, or until he has lost three games.  Think of the following scenario... you are at an arcade with \$3 at one of those crane games and you *really* want a prize that you see in there so you decide to try to get it.  It costs a dollar each time you play, so you have three chances to get it.  You put in your money and try to get the prize.  If you happen to get the prize then you are happy and stop playing.  If you run out of money, you have to stop playing.  The same thing is happening here, John has three chances to play.  If he wins he stops...

Comment: ...and if he loses three times, then he has to end.  For the crane game, we could have asked how many times we are expected to press the 'Start' button on the game.  It is the exact same problem as this problem with chess that you are asking, just different flavor.  The possibilities are: Win on the first and stop.,,  Lose on the first and win on the second and stop.,,  Lose on the first, lose on the second, and win on the third and stop.,, Lose on the first, lose on the second and lose on the third and stop.

Comment: The stopping condition isn’t that he wins the _first_ game, which is what you computed, but that he wins _some_ game.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you so much for being patient with me. I really appreciate it. "The possibilities are: Win on the first and stop.,, Lose on the first and win on the second and stop.,, Lose on the first, lose on the second, and win on the third and stop.,, Lose on the first, lose on the second and lose on the third and stop." I understand how we got this what was throwing me off was the P(win 2nd game) and the P(win 3rd game). Would it be wrong if I changed it to the P(lost 2nd game) and the P(lost 3rd game)? The set up would still be the same, no? And I would still get the correct answer.

Comment: So long as you are careful enough with your wording.  "Losing the 2nd game" doesn't by itself convey information to me as to how the sequence of events ended as we could have lost the first, lost the second, and lost the third, or we could have lost the first, lost the second, but won the third.  Saying "lost the 2nd" by itself and having that try to suggest all of the necessary information seems ambiguous to me.  If you prefer rewording it, I would reword it as I did above, maybe shortening things and writing $P(W), P(LW), P(LLW), P(LLL)$, meaning the obvious results.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you so so much. You were so patient with me and you explained everything in great detail. It was definitely the wording that was throwing me off. I will double check with my teach and see if I can reword it. Thanks again.